# Socket wait accept Close Stack

Tags: c#, sockets

I have thread that Problem when i try close the form

when i run the server 
and the thread is start the socket wait for accept
and after i open the server
i try close the server
it cannot,
it stack in NewCon.Abort();

help me please

the code is :

```
 private void ServerOn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sckServerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        sckServerSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ip, port));
        sckServerSocket.Listen(0);
        bIsOn = true;
        dicStudent = new Dictionary<Socket, Student>();
        NewCon = new Thread(getNewConnection);
        NewCon.Start();
    }

    public void getNewConnection()
    {
        while (true)
        {
                Socket sckReciveConnect = sckServerSocket.Accept();
                dicStudent.Add(sckReciveConnect, new Student(sckReciveConnect, this));
        }
    }

 private void ServerOut_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (bIsOn)
        {
            try
            {
              --->  NewCon.Abort();
                sckServerSocket.Close();

                foreach (Student stu in dicStudent.Values)
                {
                    byte[] Close = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("EXT");
                    stu.scksReciveSocket.Send(Close, 0, Close.Length, 0);
                }

                this.Close();
            }
            catch  (Exception x)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to kill the thread.  Just call `Close()` against the server and this will cause the blocking `Accept()` call to drop out with an exception:

```
// NewCon.Abort(); <-- don't do this
sckServerSocket.Close(); // just close it
```

You can trap this and break out of your loop:

```
    public void getNewConnection()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket sckReciveConnect = sckServerSocket.Accept();
                // ...
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return; // drop out of loop
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It fixing my problem tyyyyy